# Нужна помощь с бинарным рекурсивным поиском C++

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, рекурсия, поиск

### Я чувствую что у меня тут очень глупая ошибка и решение на поверхности, но мозг уже не работает...

Суть задания заключается в том что нужно выводить глубину погружения и номер элемента в массиве(по заданию обязательно нужна рекурсия)

В коде ниже подсчет глубины, как я понимаю, сделал нормально, а вот с номером элемента проблемы.
Пока писал этот пост понял что еще есть проблема с тем, что если пытаться найти элемент которого нет программа крашится...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

int f = 0;

void siftDown(int* numbers, int root, int bottom)
{
    int maxChild; // индекс максимального потомка
    int done = 0; // флаг того, что куча сформирована
    // Пока не дошли до последнего ряда
    while ((root * 2 <= bottom) && (!done))
    {
        if (root * 2 == bottom) {    // если мы в последнем ряду,   
            maxChild = root * 2;
        }   // запоминаем левый потомок
          // иначе запоминаем больший потомок из двух
        else if (numbers[root * 2] > numbers[root * 2 + 1]) {
            maxChild = root * 2;
        }
        else {
            maxChild = root * 2 + 1;
        }
        // если элемент вершины меньше максимального потомка
        if (numbers[root] < numbers[maxChild])
        {
            int temp = numbers[root]; // меняем их местами
            numbers[root] = numbers[maxChild];
            numbers[maxChild] = temp;
            root = maxChild;
        }
        else {// иначе 
            done = 1;
        } // пирамида сформирована
    }
}
// Функция сортировки на куче

void heapSort(int* numbers, int array_size)
{
    double d;
    double tn = 0;
    unsigned int start_time = clock();
    // Формируем нижний ряд пирамиды
    for (int i = (array_size / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        siftDown(numbers, i, array_size - 1);
    // Просеиваем через пирамиду остальные элементы
    for (int i = array_size - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int temp = numbers[0];
        numbers[0] = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = temp;
        siftDown(numbers, 0, i - 1);       
    }
}

// функция с алгоритмом двоичного поиска 
int Search_Binary(int arr[], int left, int right, int key, long int midd)
{
    midd = (left + right) / 2;

    if (key < arr[midd]) {       // если искомое меньше значения в ячейке
        right = midd - 1;       // смещаем правую границу поиска
        f++;
        Search_Binary(arr, left, right, key, midd);    
    }
    else if (key > arr[midd]) { // если искомое больше значения в ячейке
        left = midd + 1;        // смещаем левую границу поиска
        f++;
        Search_Binary(arr, left, right, key, midd);
    }
    else {                       // иначе (значения равны)        
        cout << "Глубина погружения: " << f <<endl;
        f = 0;
        return midd;            // функция возвращает индекс ячейки
    }
    if (left > right)           // если границы сомкнулись 
        return -1;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int t = 0,index;
    int testMass[9];
    int key = 0;

    cout << "Заполните тестовый массив из 8 элементов\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cin >> testMass[i];
    }
    heapSort(testMass, 8);
    cout << "Вывод массива:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        cout << testMass[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << "\nВведите число для поиска: ";
    cin >> key;
    index = Search_Binary(testMass, 0, 8, key,0);
    if (index >= 0)
        cout << "Указанное число находится в ячейке с индексом: " << index+1;
    else
        cout << "В массиве нет такого числа!";
    key = 0;
    cout << "\n";

    // Сортировка 6000-9000 элементов c шагом в 1000. в 3-х случаях.
    for (int n = 300000; n <= 500000; n = n + 100000) {
        t++;

        int* b = new int[n];

        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" << "n" << t << " = " << n <<"\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) b[i] = rand();
        cout << "Введите число для поиска: ";
        cin >> key;
        heapSort(b, n);
        index = Search_Binary(b, 0, n-1, key,0);
        if (index >= 0)
            cout << "Указанное число находится в ячейке с индексом: " << index+1;
        else
            cout << "В массиве нет такого числа!";       
        key = 0;                
        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";      
        delete[] b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "глубина погружения"? Вывод что вы привели верный или нет? Что он означает? Дополните вопрос

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Глубина погружения - сколько раз функция вызывает сама себя. Вывод не верный. В моё выводе ищется число 3. Ячейка должна указываться 3-я

Comment: напишите это в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Вы забываете возвращать позицию найденного элемента. Т.е. нужно не просто рекурсивно вызывать `Search_Binary`, а возвращать её значение.
Вот (не идеальная) реализация:

```
int Search_Binary(int arr[], int left, int right, int key)
{
    if (left > right)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int midd = (left + right) / 2;
        if (key == arr[midd])
        {
            return midd;    
        }
        else if (arr[midd] > key)
        {
            return Search_Binary(arr, left, midd - 1, key);
        }
        else if (arr[midd] < key)
        {
            return Search_Binary(arr, midd + 1, right, key);
        }
    }
 }
```

Функция принимает индекс начала и конца диапазона и возвращает индекс найденного элемента.
Думаю, поиск глубины прикрутите сами:)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Так и знал что ошибка глупая